# Xml not loading into flash properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi im trying to learn flash actionscript 3.0 basically i just want to learn how to put 1 simple picture into a flash document using XML so far ive got

```
<Gallery>
<IMAGE TITLE="Picture">Desert.jpg</IMAGE>
</Gallery>
```

thats my XML code DESERT is a picture on my laptop from the sample pictures

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("pictest.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML(e:Event):void {
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
trace(myXML.*);
}
```

this is my flash code when i run it i get a ton of errors which im confused about im new to this so any help would be appreciated also the myLoader is a textarea box with the instance name myLoader

Thanks in advance Rhys

Comment: Get rid of that asterisk in `trace(myXML.*);` and post the errors you are getting.

Comment: Also, myLoader should not be a text area AND a URLLoader - make sure you use unambiguous names.

Comment: and put the addEventListener line before the load() command

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must change the order. First the event listener and after that the event.

```
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML); 
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("pictest.xml"));
```

Greetings,